# What do you call the market for a certain job?

Tags: phrases, idiomatic-language

I am not sure, but the only phrase that comes to mind is "X market" as in "janitor market", but I think it may sound odd in certain situation.

Here's an example that might help understand what I mean:

> Because the young generation don't want to do labor-intensive work,
>   there was a huge lack of labor in the janitor market, which drove the
>   wage for janitorial work through the roof to the point they earned
>   more than most white-collar workers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The job *market* relates to the entire pool of jobs available.  When formally referring to one particular job (or kind of job) use instead "field":

> There is a huge demand in the **janitorial field**

That being said, "field" is normally associated with certain white-collar jobs, but overly formal when talking about blue-collar jobs.  Instead I would say something like:

> There is a huge demand for **janitors**.

A group of related jobs can be collectively referred to as a "sector":

> There remains high demand for jobs in the **technical sector**, particularly programmers who have the latest buzzword on their resumes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain your sentence as much as possible, I would simply use *job market* and qualify it with the appropriate adjective:

> There was a huge lack of labor in the <s>janitor</s> ***janitorial*** *job* market.